# Weird behavior of INDIRECT function in Google Sheets. Only works after cut and paste

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with multiple tabs. An especific tab ("main_tab") gets data from another tab ("other_tab") using the INDIRECT function. I'm using INDIRECT function beacause I need that the reference keep unchanged every time I change the name of another tab.

As can be seen in the video, the data in "main_tab" changes only after I cut and paste in the same place the content of the cells (?!?!). It should change in the moment I change the content of the "another_tab".

The video above starts after I change the data and show the cut ("recortar" in portuguese) and paste ("colar" in portuguese).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBdoTGy7Iv0&feature=youtu.be

Any clues how to solve this, or it's just a Google Sheets bug?

Comment: If you could write down the formulas you are using or sharing a link to a sample Google Sheet it would be easier to help out.

Comment: Here is a copy of the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T3j6ZoJTyEjRy3MKdMY68RABMnyQt-r2zP0rQFizwwE/edit?usp=sharing  When I change the name of the tabs "Cha_XX_XX_2019" to "Chamados", it must change the values in "Auxiliar" tab. But the change only happens when i cut and paste the cells with the values.

Answer (score 1):

This other question might serve you right from the start: [References changing in Google Sheets with new forms submissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260595/references-changing-in-google-sheets-with-new-forms-submissions)

You can also try to use the formula like an array. For example:

For direct reference:

```
=ArrayFormula(INDIRECT("'main_tab'!A:A"))
```

If you are using formulas:

```
=COUNTA(indirect("main_tab!I2:I"))
```

Or if you want nested formulas:

```
=COUNTIFS(indirect("main_tab!$AD2:$AD"),"data_A ",INDIRECT("other tab!$AA2:$AA"),"data_b")
```

For references and documentation:

-Here is the Indirect function official explanation from Google:
[NDIRECTO (INDIRECT)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=es)

-Here is a tutorial with examples: 
[Google Sheets Indirect Function Examples and Usage](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/google-sheets-indirect-function-examples-usage/)

-And if you require ranges: 
[Google Sheets: INDIRECT() with a Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541923/google-sheets-indirect-with-a-range])